# How do I return all children of a tree, given a level?

Tags: javascript, tree

Suppose I have an array like this

```
let tree = [
  { 
    id: 8,
    level: 1,
    children: [
      { 
        id: 3,
        level: 2,
        children: [
          { 
            id: 1,
            level: 3,
            children: [] 
          }, 
          { 
            id: 6, 
            level: 3,
            children: [ 
              { id: 4, level: 4, children: [] }, 
              { id: 7, level: 4, children: [] } 
            ]
          }
        ] 
      },
      { 
        id: 10,
        level: 2,
        children: [ 
          { 
            id: 14,
            level: 3,
            children: [
              { id: 13, level: 4, children: [] }
            ] 
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get all children with a given level.  So in the function if I provide a level of 3, I should get there children and there children's children (if at all).

Here is the function I have so far.  Oddly enough it works for level 2 but nothing else.

```
function searchTree(node, level){
  let resultArr = [];
  if(node.children){
    node.children.forEach( (n) => {
      if(n.level === level){
        resultArr.push(n);
      }
        searchTree(n, n.level);
    })
  }
  return resultArr;
}
```

Comment: This smells like a reason to use reduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least four errors:

1. you are not passing resultArr around, so it cannot accumulate results.
2. you keep looking at children even after you found that their parent has the searched level - that is a waste of time.
3. you are making the recursive call with the node's level instead of the level that you are searching for.
4. your code does not work for first level, because you never check the top node, just its children.

Try this version:

```
function searchTree(node, level, resultArr)
{
  if (node)
  {
    if (node.level === level)
    {
      resultArr.push(node);
    }
    else if (node.children)
    {
      node.children.forEach((n) => {searchTree(n, level, resultArr);})
    }
  }
}
```

You also don't need to store the level in the nodes; you can compute it instead as you do the recursive calls (if you're called with currentLevel, just call your children with currentLevel + 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let resultArr = [];
    function searchTree(node, level){
      if(node.children){
        node.children.forEach( (n) => {
          if(n.level === level){
            resultArr.push(n);
          }
            searchTree(n, level);
        })
      }
      return resultArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let tree = [ { id: 8, level: 1, children: [ { id: 3, level: 2, children: [ { id: 1, level: 3, children: [] }, { id: 6, level: 3, children: [ { id: 4, level: 4, children: [] }, { id: 7, level: 4, children: [] } ] } ] }, { id: 10, level: 2, children: [ { id: 14, level: 3, children: [ { id: 13, level: 4, children: [] } ] } ] } ] } ]
let resultArr = [];
function searchTree(node, level) {
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach((n) => {
      if (n.level === level) {
        resultArr.push(n);
      }
      searchTree(n, level);
    })
  }
  return resultArr;
}
searchTree(tree[0], 3);
console.log(resultArr);
```